# Does Apache HTTP Server Reverse Proxy send SNI?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, sni

I want to use Apache HTTP server as a Reverse Proxy for a set of microservices hosted in OpenShift or Kubernetes.
I want to use TLS passthrough on Kubernetes route. i.e. a TLS connection needs to be created at Apache (outbound) and terminate at the pod.
To make this happen, OpenShift needs to identify the target host without decrypting the payload so that it can forward each request to the correct microservice.
Server Name Indication (SNI) in TLS will have the host name. 
I tried with IBM HTTP Server (IHS), which is based on Apache. However, IBM HTTP Server does not sent SNI information in the outbound TLS connection. (Connection initiated by mod proxy between the IBM HTTP Server and OpenShift). OpenShift throws an error. The documentation mentions that IHS doesn't support SNI on the outbound side, even on the latest releases.
I am trying to find out whether latest Apache HTTP server can send SNI information on the outbound when configured as a reverse proxy. I could not find any documentation which clearly mentions this.
Thanks

Comment: This is defined by the OpenSSL version and configuration, not by Apache. Off topic.

Comment: Do you know where I could find any OpenSSL documentation about configuring SNI? I've been googling for days, no luck yet. Could only find info about SNI on the inbound side of Apache.

Comment: Maybe OpenShift can listen on several ports, and each port will be dedicated to one microservice ?

Comment: No, unfortunately OpenShift usually listens on 80(HTTP) and 443(HTTPS). If we try to open different ports for different microservices, then I believe we loose the purpose of having the OpenShift/Kubernetes architecture in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I configured an Apache as an SSL Reverse Proxy and it seems to work correctly for the SNI part. Although not documented clearly as you mentionned yourself.

I'm running :

```
# /usr/local/httpd-2.4.29.tuned/bin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec 24 2017 19:19:13
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

Here's my conf when forwarding to www.stackoverflow.com

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
SSLSessionTickets on
SSLProxyVerify none
ProxyPreserveHost Off

<IfModule proxy_module>
  ProxyPass             /     https://www.stackoverflow.com/
  ProxyPassReverse      /     https://www.stackoverflow.com/
</IfModule>
```

And here's some tcpdump where you see the SNI at the very end between the 2 * chars

```
20:27:06.506832 IP XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX.14685 > 8.8.8.8.53: 45945+ A? www.stackoverflow.com. (39)
stackoverflow.com......5./...y...........www
20:27:06.520988 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX.14685: 45945 5/0/0 CNAME stackoverflow.com., A 151.101.1.69, A 151.101.65.69, A 151.101.129.69, A 151.101.193.69 (117)
stackoverflow.com.............._.................e.E.............eAE.............e.E.............e.E
20:27:06.521566 IP XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX.56781 > 151.101.1.69.443: Flags [S], seq 2876049156, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 941503620 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<3.@.@.u../?q.e.E.....m........9..y.........
8.4.........
20:27:06.535770 IP 151.101.1.69.443 > XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX.56781: Flags [S.], seq 3281327361, ack 2876049157, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 967826870 ecr 941503620,nop,wscale 9], length 0
E..<..@.<..q.e.E./?q.........m....q V..........
9...8.4....
20:27:06.535846 IP XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX.56781 > 151.101.1.69.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 941503635 ecr 967826870], length 0
E..43.@.@.u../?q.e.E.....m.........s.q.....
8.4.9...
20:27:06.536252 IP XXX.YYY.ZZZ.XXX.56781 > 151.101.1.69.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 115, options [nop,nop,TS val 941503635 ecr 967826870], length 517
E..93.@.@.s../?q.e.E.....m.........s.v.....
8.4.9................2.X.OQ.W..[. ...x...48.g....Z.....0.,.(.$...
.........k.j.i.h.9.8.7.6.........2...*.&.......=.5.../.+.'.#... .........g.@.?.>.3.2.1.0.E.D.C.B.1.-.).%.......<./.A.................E.........**www.stackoverflow.com**.........
```

Good luck